# Using craft.entries to return entries with empty entries field

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

I'm new to all this. Is it possible to use `craft.entries` to return all entries with an empty entries field? Something like:

```
{% set drinksWithNoIngredients = craft.entries.section("drinks").ingredients(":empty:") %}
{% for drink in drinksWithNoIngredients %}
    <p>Do something with {{ drink.title }}...</p>
```

where `ingredients` is an entries field handle. This doesn't seem to work on entries fields, though. Or maybe I could do some kind of `relatedTo` magic, where the `targetElement` is some kind of special null value?

An alternative seems to be this:

```
{% set drinksWithNoIngredients = craft.entries.section("drinks") %}
{% for drink in drinksWithNoIngredients %}
    {% if not drink.ingredients.total() %}
    <p>Do something with {{ drink.title }}...</p>
```

But doing it that way calls `.total()` on *every* drink. Is that going to cause performance problems if I have a lot of drinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track using `relatedTo`. But as there's no `notRelatedTo` parameter, you'd first have to get all drinks that are related to any ingredient and those entries can then be removed from a new ElementCriteriaModel, that returns all your drinks, using Craft's [`without`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#without) filter. Instead of passing whole element models, you should better use this filter with element IDs (→ [Why is the Craft without filter not working correctly and how to debug?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/7170/125)). To get them just make use of the [`ids()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#ids) method.

```
{% set ingredients = craft.entries.section('ingredients').limit(null) %}
{% set drinksWithIngredientsIds = craft.entries.section('drinks').relatedTo({targetElement: ingredients}).limit(null).ids() %}

{% set drinksWithNoIngredients = craft.entries.section('drinks')|without(drinksWithIngredientsIds) %}
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks so much. On a minor note, I had to change the last line to retrieve ids: `{% set drinksWithNoIngredientsIds = craft.entries.section('drinks').ids()|without(drinksWithIngredientsIds) %}` for the `without` filter to kick in. I then was able to get all the entries I wanted via: `craft.entries.id(drinksWithNoIngredientsIds)`.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what role does the `.limit(null)` parameter play in the first two lines of code?

Comment: `limit` is set to 100 by default. So it just makes sure you include all the ingredients, last line is for the output and you can limit or paginate to your liking.